# Security in java backend for Angular App controlled by OAM

Tags: java, angular, security, oam

I have developed Angular(2) application , backend is developed in Java (JAX-RS). Both Angular and backend has same context.

Server side: Application is OAM controlled , when I open app page in browser i get OAM login page; once login, app home page opens.

Now i have requirement, put extra security in app, if OAM goes wrong/down app should work. To achieve this i used jspFilters and in web.xml added CLIENT_CERT, FORM. With these changes my app is showing extra login page after OAM login page.
But i am expecting; if OAM authenticates first then carry forward internal login and shouldn't ask login again. If OAM is not there then ask for login.

can anyone help me, how can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance
Ch

Comment: "first then carry forward internal login and shouldn't ask login again"..can't you implement this logic in your jsp filter code?

Comment: I dont know how to do, can you help me implementing the same. Actually i haven't done any security implementations before first time i am doing it.

Comment: typo in in my issue description, its not jspFilter, its jpsFilter in web.xml